# QTcpSocket - Check if is connected

Tags: c++, qt

Trying to connect:

```
QTcpSocket *tcpClient = new QTcpSocket(this);
tcpClient->connectToHost(ip_address, portNumber);
```

But `connectToHost` returns void.
So what should I do to check up if `tcpClient` is connected to the given address and port ?
 How can I give this connection attempt an allowed timeout and check connection state when timeout expires ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[QAbstractSocket::waitForConnected](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractsocket.html#waitForConnected) will give you exactly what you want if you are able to block the current thread until connection or timeout.  If not, then use the signal [QAbstractSocket::stateChanged](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractsocket.html#stateChanged).  E.g. in your class declaration have

```
class C
{
    public slots:
        void HandleStateChange(AbstractSocket::SocketState socketState );
   ...
};
```

define it, obviously, and then after `tcpClient` is declared have

```
connect(tcpClient, SIGNAL(stateChanged(AbstractSocket::SocketState)), 
            this, SLOT(HandleStateChange(AbstractSocket::SocketState)));
```

This, in conjunction with timed queries to `tcpClient->state()`, will tell you exactly what's going on to the socket and let you respond to it.

Comment: Seems missed a parenthesis at `connect`:)  How can I edit just a parethesis ?

Comment: @CDT I think the system forces 3rd-party editors to make longer edits only, I've seen this myself--but thanks, taken care of!